# Group by ID and apply a condition on the value of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am new to pandas library and I would appreciate your help.
This is my input

| ID | DATE | LABEL | STOCK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 01/26/2020 | **TRUE** | 100 |
| AA | 01/27/2020 | FALSE | 200 |
| BB | 01/28/2020 | FALSE | 300 |
| BB | 01/29/2020 | **TRUE** | 500 |
| BB | 01/30/2020 | FALSE | 100 |
| CC | 01/26/2020 | **TRUE** | 200 |
| CC | 01/27/2020 | FALSE | 300 |
| CC | 01/28/2020 | FALSE | 100 |
| CC | 01/29/2020 | **TRUE** | 400 |

I would like to look at the Label column and for the first "TRUE" label that is found for each ID I need to copy the value of stock in a new column. If an ID has more than one TRUE I need to consider only the first one.

Here is the output i want to obtain:

| ID | DATE | LABEL | STOCK | NEW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 01/26/2020 | **TRUE** | 100 | 100 |
| AA | 01/27/2020 | FALSE | 200 |  |
| BB | 01/28/2020 | FALSE | 300 |  |
| BB | 01/29/2020 | **TRUE** | 500 | 500 |
| BB | 01/30/2020 | FALSE | 100 |  |
| CC | 01/26/2020 | **TRUE** | 200 | 200 |
| CC | 01/27/2020 | FALSE | 300 |  |
| CC | 01/28/2020 | FALSE | 100 |  |
| CC | 01/29/2020 | **TRUE** | 400 |  |

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what have you tried so far and what does your code look like?

Comment: I have tried groupby  with apply and later with transform but i wasn't able to write the lambda function

Comment: It looks like you want to GroupBy ID, and then use the operator "GroupBy.first".   That should give you the DataFrame you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another version, using `.groupby()`:

```
m = df.index.isin(
    df[df["LABEL"] == True].reset_index().groupby("ID").index.first()
)
df.loc[m, "NEW"] = df.loc[m, "STOCK"]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID        DATE  LABEL  STOCK    NEW
0  AA  01/26/2020   True    100  100.0
1  AA  01/27/2020  False    200    NaN
2  BB  01/28/2020  False    300    NaN
3  BB  01/29/2020   True    500  500.0
4  BB  01/30/2020  False    100    NaN
5  CC  01/26/2020   True    200  200.0
6  CC  01/27/2020  False    300    NaN
7  CC  01/28/2020  False    100    NaN
8  CC  01/29/2020   True    400    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

use a double boolean with `.duplicated()`

```
df.loc[df['LABEL'].eq(True) & 
      df.duplicated(subset=['ID'],keep='last'),'NEW'] = df['STOCK']


print(df.fillna(''))

   ID        DATE  LABEL  STOCK  NEW
0  AA  01/26/2020   True    100  100
1  AA  01/27/2020  False    200     
2  BB  01/28/2020  False    300     
3  BB  01/29/2020   True    500  500
4  BB  01/30/2020  False    100     
5  CC  01/26/2020   True    200  200
6  CC  01/27/2020  False    300     
7  CC  01/28/2020  False    100     
8  CC  01/29/2020   True    400
```

---

looking at each boolean, we only want the values where both are true.

```
df.assign(ky1=df['LABEL'].eq(True),
         ky2=df.duplicated(subset=['ID'],keep='last')
         )


   ID        DATE  LABEL  STOCK    NEW    ky1    ky2
0  AA  01/26/2020   True    100  100.0   True   True
1  AA  01/27/2020  False    200    NaN  False  False
2  BB  01/28/2020  False    300    NaN  False   True
3  BB  01/29/2020   True    500  500.0   True   True
4  BB  01/30/2020  False    100    NaN  False  False
5  CC  01/26/2020   True    200  200.0   True   True
6  CC  01/27/2020  False    300    NaN  False   True
7  CC  01/28/2020  False    100    NaN  False   True
8  CC  01/29/2020   True    400    NaN   True  False
```