# Group by id and change column value based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm a bit stuck on some code. I've looked through stack and found many similar questions but all are different in some way.

I have a dataframe `df_jan` which looks like this.

```
df_jan
ID            Date          days_since_last_purchase         x_1
1           01/01/2020               0                        0
1           04/01/2020               3                        0
2           04/01/2020               0                        0
1           06/02/2020               33                       1
```

Basically `x_1` denotes whether it has been over 30 days since their last purchase.

What I want to achieve is if an ID has `x_1 = 1` anywhere in its lifetime all the `x_1` values for that specific ID is set to 1 like this.

```
df_jan
ID               Date        days_since_last_purchase     x_1
1               01/01/2020              0                  1
1               04/01/2020              3                  1
2               04/01/2020              0                  0
1               06/02/2020              33                 1
```

I've tried using a `.groupby` function along with a `.loc` but it says they can't work together. I also tried modifying the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67291004/group-by-id-and-apply-a-condition-on-the-value-of-one-column) without much luck.

Thank you in advance for any help you guys can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can groupby and transform, eg:

```
df['x_1'] = df_jan.groupby('ID')['days_since_last_purchase'].transform(lambda v: int(v.gt(30).any()))
```